# Reading value from QML in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to read an `int value` from my `QML` side on `c++` but this value remains `0` and doesn't update on `c++` side while `console.log()` clearly shows me that it increments after each click . What am I doing wrong here?

**.qml file**

```
FocusScope {

        property alias myrecordint: startbutton.recordint

        Rectangle {
            id: buttonPaneShadow
            width: bottomColumn.width + 16
            height: parent.height
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: "white"

            Column {
                anchors {
                    right: parent.right
                    top: parent.top
                    margins: 8
                }

                id: buttonsColumn
                anchors.rightMargin: 20
                anchors.topMargin: 20
                spacing: 12

                CameraButton {
                    id: startbutton
                    property int recordint:0
                    text: "Record"
                    visible: camera.videoRecorder.recorderStatus == CameraRecorder.LoadedStatus
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        recordint=recordint+1
                        camera.videoRecorder.record()
                        console.log(recordint)

                    }
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

**.cpp file**

```
   QQmlEngine engine;
   QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/VideoCaptureControls.qml"));
   QObject *object = component.create();
   qDebug() << "Property value:" << QQmlProperty::read(object, "myrecordint").toInt();
```

Comment: It is a very bad way to expose c++ to qml or vice versa. Qt already offers a way to connect your c++ classes with qml objects, please read here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html before develop your application.

Comment: @arnes Thank you so much I will definitely go through that link! I'm not that much experienced in QML but this helps!

Comment: you're very welcome, if you get stuck somewhere you can look the examples 
 https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlextendingexamples.html

Comment: @arnes Wow you're amazing thanks! I can see that there are examples about exporting `C++ Properties and Classes`. Are there any minimal examples about exporting `QML properties` as I need to access a `QML Object` on my `c++` side?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-adding-example.html actually this example shows how to do that. Declare and define Person class. After, at main.cpp, before `engine.load( "your_qml.qml" )` called, add this piece of code, `qmlRegisterType<Person>( "your_module_name" , 1 /*major version of your module*/ , 2 /*minor version of your module*/ , "Person" /*Qml type name*/ );` so it tells to qml engine to expose `Person` class to `qml` side. You can access your properties also you can also call `public slots:` functions from qml side

Comment: @arnes Alrighty! Thank you so much! I will play around with to see if I can make it work out!

Comment: see my answer to similar question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70176831/4780334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

After commenting back and forth, it seems you are not using the instance you should use, since you are creating a new instance on a button click.

Also, the reading of the property is execute-once and not auto-updated.

All-in-all this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) and you should strive to use a C++ model as also pointed out by Arnes ([example 1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) and [example 2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-adding-example.html))

**Original answer** (wrong since the property *is* top-level)

You can only read properties from the top-level of a QML object (when reading from outside the object). You should move the property as suggested below:

```
Rectangle {
        id: buttonPaneShadow
        width: bottomColumn.width + 16
        height: parent.height
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        color: "white"

        property int recordint:0 //move to here

        Column {
            anchors {
                right: parent.right
                top: parent.top
                margins: 8
            }

            id: buttonsColumn
            anchors.rightMargin: 20
            anchors.topMargin: 20
            spacing: 12

            CameraButton {
                id: startbutton
                text: "Record"
                visible: camera.videoRecorder.recorderStatus == CameraRecorder.LoadedStatus
                onClicked:
                {
                    recordint=recordint+1
                    camera.videoRecorder.record()
                    console.log(recordint)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Personally, I dislike the way you seem to implement this. I would rather go for a C++ model with properties that get updated, but that's up to you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. actually there was a mistake on my code. I have edited the code. my property is top-level I assume (if I am wrong kindly correct me as I'm not good in `QML`)

Comment: If it's not too much to ask would you also please give me a reference to such a c++ model? Personally I'm not a fan of the method that I have chosen either I just did it this way because I'm not aware of other methods :)

Comment: @Raad I see you already got the hint about the C++ models. To answer your other question: your property is not top-level of the qml file (assuming that is the one you load in attached .cpp file), since it is in one of the components that you qml file creates

Comment: Yes that is correct. but I'm passing `property int recordint` to `property alias myrecordint` which is top-level and then read it in .cpp. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Raad well that's funny then... apart from the advise of using C++ models, I'd like to understand why this fails, because it actually shouldn't. Can you tell when you where reading the property in C++ code? (continuous or only once after the loading  in the .cpp snippet)

Comment: I execute the `c++` code block I included in the question every time I click on a `QpushButton`. could that be the problem? maybe I reread the .qml file on every click?

Comment: So that means you are creating a new `VideoCaptureControls` on every click? In that case it's no wonder you are always reading 0 and you should definitely follow the C++ model route ;-)

Comment: I see. so it is one time executable ? I will definitely move to c++ model but just wondering how is it possible to get the most recent QML object value instead of the initialized one in this method? is that even possible?

Comment: It's a one-time execute yes, but also, most probably you are not reading the value you think you should (I assume you have a running qml gui and are creating a non-visible object every time you click you QPushButton). About possibility: there might be a chance you can get the changed signal, so that you can read the new value, or you can do it based on a QTimer, but really: _don't_ ;-)

Comment: Thank you and Arnes for your helps! although I haven't solved the problem yet but I will mark your answer as accepted since it has covered the issue with details!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of code to read qml data from c

```
QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
QObject *pageOne = rootObject->findChild<QObject*>("page1box");

//calling qml function from c
QVariant returnedValue;
QVariant msg = "Hello from C++";
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pageOne, "myQmlFunction",
    Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
    Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));
qDebug() << "QML function returned:" << returnedValue.toString();
```